# Writing to the files simultaneously in Excel Macro

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I am preparing excel macro to read data from Input file and output it to two different file depending on condition.

Code Snippet as below

```
   fileName1="test1.txt"
   fileName2="test2.txt"
   file1 = FreeFile()
   file2 = FreeFile()

   Open fileName1 For Output As file1
   Open fileName2 For Output As file2

   If Condition1=true Then
       sWrite1="Write to file 1"
       print #file1,sWrite1
   Else
       sWrite2="Write to file 2"
       print #file2,sWrite2
   End If

   Close #file1
   Close #file2
```

Expected output is "Write to file 1" should go to file1 
and "Write to file 2" should be to file2.

But after running the macro ,
both "Write to file 1" and "Write to file 2" were written to file2 
and file1 is empty.

Can anyone please help me on how to write simultaneously to two files.

Comment: Take a closer look on your line `Open fileName 1 For Output as file1` and under this, you have again `Open fileName1` so maybe this can cause issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`FreeFile()` returns the next file number available for opening. When you call it twice in a row like you did, it returns the same value (probably 1) in both cases since you haven't yet used the file number, making it still available for opening.

Instead, you need to use that file number before you invoke `FreeFile()` again.

Change

```
file1 = FreeFile()
file2 = FreeFile()

Open fileName1 For Output As file1
Open fileName2 For Output As file2
```

to

```
file1 = FreeFile()
Open fileName1 For Output As file1

file2 = FreeFile()
Open fileName2 For Output As file2
```

and it will work as expected.